# Tabulator - change font size for entire table

Tags: tabulator

I would like to be able to increase the font size for an entire tabulator table in version 5.1. I know that I can increase the font size of a column by using a custom formatter, but I have a column with editable text and it does not appear that I can have a custom formatter with editable text.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.tabulator`

```
<style>
  .tabulator {
    font-size: 28px;  // change font size
  }
</style>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doublehrajput/j07q6fx3/2/)

Comment: This is the simplest solution, Tabulator just uses standard CSS for styling so there is no need for anything more complicated